# Template not rendering in django

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to make an invoice reciept which takes data from a django Database and render that data on a template. Data is stored and can be shown in terminal that data is well stored in that model. I've done it several times but I cannot figure out why data is not rendered in my template.

This is my Models.py

```
class LR(models.Model):
    lr_quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quiz_lr')

    lr_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lr_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=255, default=now)
    lr_billingparty = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)  # supplier company name foreign key

    invoice_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lr_declared = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ewaybill_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lr_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # quantity
    lr_weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # weight

    lr_invoice_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=255, default=now)

    lr_item_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)  # said to contain

    lr_consignor_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)  # shipper company name
    lr_consignor_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)  # shipper company name
    lr_consignor_contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)  # shipper company name
    lr_consignor_contact_phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)  # shipper company name

    lr_consignee_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)  # shipper company name
    lr_consignee_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)  # shipper company name
    lr_consignee_contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)  # shipper company name
    lr_consignee_contact_phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)  # shipper company name

    vehicle_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    lr_vehicle_type = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    driver_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    driver_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def str (self):
    return self.name
```

This is my views.py:

```
def PrintLR (request, pk):
    LR = get_object_or_404(LR, lr_quiz_id=pk)
    context_object_name = 'LR'
    template_name = 'classroom/suppliers/showLR.html'
    return render(request, 'classroom/suppliers/showLR.html', {LR:'LR'})
```

This is my HTML template:

```
<tr>
    <th>CNOTE NO</th>
    <th>BOOKING DATE</th>
    <th>BILLING PARTY</th>



</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ LR.lr_consignor_contact_phone }}</td>
    <td>{{ LR.lr_declared }}</td>
    <td>{{ LR.lr_consignee_name }}</td>
</tr>
```

No data is seen in template, rather fields are empty.

Comment: Is template is not rendered or context data is not rendered?

Comment: Hi chirag, while rendering the template you are providing `{LR:'LR'}` but in client you are trying to access LR.some_property. First of all there is only one string in LR, that is 'LR'. Try to assign a dict value, without quotes, like `{'LR':LR}`

Comment: Eg: `LR = dict(); LR.lr_consignor_contact_phone="733849"; return render(request, 'classroom/suppliers/showLR.html', {'LR':LR})`

Comment: @shafik Template is rendered but no data is shown in that template. All the fields are blank.

Comment: @PrasanthGanesan well that's an amazing way of doing this but don't it always gives me static data which I assigned rather then fetching data from database in realtime?

Comment: That's only an example. You are enclosing value within quotes. But you need to enclose key with quotes and pass the value as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This :

```
return render(request, 'classroom/suppliers/showLR.html', {LR:'LR'})
```

is wrong - you're using the model instance as key and the literal string `'LR'` as value, so there's nothing named "LR" in your template context. What you want is

```
return render(request, 'classroom/suppliers/showLR.html', {'LR':LR})
```

notice that this time we're using the string as key and the instance as value.

As a side note, you shouldn't name your instance the same as the class - it's confusing at best and can lead to unexpected behaviours since it shadows the class in the rest of the current scope. Oh and yes: the `context_object_name = 'LR'` part is totally useless.

Comment: I'm soembarrassed. That was such a silly mistake. Thank you so much in pointing out that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Change in `PrintLR` method

```
def PrintLR (request, pk):
    qwe = get_object_or_404(LR, lr_quiz_id=pk)
    template_name = 'classroom/suppliers/showLR.html'
    return render(request, 'classroom/suppliers/showLR.html', {qwe:'qwe'})
```

First, make sure it returns an object.

```
qwe = get_object_or_404(LR, lr_quiz_id=pk)
```

Then in template

```
<td>{{ qwe.lr_consignor_contact_phone }}</td>
<td>{{ qwe.lr_declared }}</td>
<td>{{ qwe.lr_consignee_name }}</td>
```

Comment: I've edited the code now. It was LR rather than qwe. Problem is still not solved.

Comment: try to print `qwe`. Is it has value?

Comment: Yes it does, It returns  me an object and any property of qwe, lets say 'qwe.lr_consignor_contact_phone ' returns me a phone number on terminal.

Comment: Yes it does, It returns me an object and any property of qwe, lets say 'qwe.lr_consignor_contact_phone ' returns me a phone number on terminal

Comment: give what you get in console